# Jquery Fancybox shadows not displaying in IE7/IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Here's the demo page:

http://www.scirra.com/stuff/startpage.html

As you can see the popup has a shadow around it in every browser except IE7/IE8.  Can anyone tell me how I can get the shadow to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox uses images in IE7 / IE8, because they don't support CSS shadows.

The CSS are linking to those IMG files with ex.

```
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-nw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Try changing the path to just `fancy_shadow_nw.png`, since they are in the same directory as the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to be pointing to the wrong location!  This doesn't seem to fix it though, I changed all paths in the CSS as you suggested, as well as changing to `fb/fancybox/` incase it worked relative from the file for that special filter, but still no luck :(

Comment: Ah never mind!  This is almost the correct answer.  The image filters needs to be relative to the document loading it.  Changing them all to `sp/fb/fancybox` has fixed the issue.  Many thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah tahts right. Had the exact same problem last time i used fancybox. Just forgot it had to be according to the page, not css - doH! :P

Answer (score 0):

The plugin must be using the CSS 3 `box-shadow` property, which IE7/8 do not support. See the [support matrix](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow). One way to fallback is to use [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) and add a rule for browsers w/o box-shadow support, and, for them, draw borders instead.